# Reading HTML content into java program

Tags: java, url

I am trying to get recharge plan information of service provider into my java program, the website contains dynamic data, and when i am fetching the URL using URLConnection i am only getting the static content,I want to automate the recharge plans of different website into my program.

```
package com.fs.store.test;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyURLConnection 
{

    private static final String baseTataUrl = "https://www.tatadocomo/pre-paypacks";`enter code here`

    public MyURLConnection()
    {

    }

    public void getMeData() 
    {
        URLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
            try
                {
                    URL url = new URL(baseTataUrl);
                    urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                     connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;

                         in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()/*,"UTF-8"*/));
                         String currentLine = null;

                    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

                         while((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                         {  
                              System.out.println(currentLine);
                              line = line.append(currentLine.trim());
                         } 
                      }catch(IOException e)
                      {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                        finally{
                            try{
                                in.close();
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
        } 

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        MyURLConnection test = new MyURLConnection();
        System.out.println("About to call getMeData()");
        test.getMeData();
    }


}
```

Comment: Can we see the Java code that you have tried to read the HTML please.

Comment: Without the code it's hard to help you

Answer (score 1):

You must use one of HtmlEditorKits
with Javascript enabled in your browser
and then get content.
See examples: 
[oreilly](http://examples.oreilly.com/jswing2/code/goodies/HtmlEdKit.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the traffjc. Firefox has a TamperData plugin for instance. Then you may communicate more directly.

Use apache's HttpClient to facilitate the communication, instead of plain URL.

Maybe use some JSON library if JSON data are coming back.

More details, but you might now skip some loading.